# Yii : multiple databases connection fails

Tags: database, yii, multiple-databases

i read the yii docs and the following code should work;

well, it doesnt. :))

db is the primary database

db1 and db2 are the secondary databases

what is wrong here ?

the website is online, at `www.linkbook.co`, and it cant connect to any of the databases

```
'db' => array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=linkbookco',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => '',
),

    'db1' => array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=linkbookco1',
    'username'         => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => '',
    'class'            => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
),

    'db2' => array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=linkbookco2',
    'username'         => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => '',
    'class'            => 'CDbConnection'          // DO NOT FORGET THIS!
),
```

Comment: the select query works now, dont really know how to insert info in the seccondary db's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`db` is the predefined component of `Yii`, so bedefault `CActiveRecord` makes connection using `db`. So for other components you have created using `CDbConnection` class you have to activate connection for them externally.

SO You need to overwrite `getDbConnection()` method of `CActiveRecord`.

Extend the `CActiveRecord` for specific database connection like `db1`.
Save this as `Db1CActiveRecord.php` and place in components directory.

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * Used for db1 database connection
 *
 */
class Db1CActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord {

    private static $db1 = null;

    public function getDbConnection()
    {
        if (self::$db1 !== null)
            return self::$db1;
        else
        {
            self::$db1 = Yii::app()->db1;
            if (self::$db1 instanceof CDbConnection)
            {
                self::$db1->setActive(true);
                return self::$db1;
            }
            else
                throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to use `Db1CActiveRecord` for the model class of database `db1`.
Like:

```
class Db1Model extends Db1CActiveRecord{
   ......
}
```

Implement this way for both db1 & db2 database.

Comment: 10x, and also, if i want to set a parameter, from 1 to 999999, parameter that automaticaly changes the database, how do i do that ?

Comment: i have 1 main db, and many secondary db's, the main db knows where the info needs to be distribuited, using a parameter, with values from 1 to .... 999999; how do i modify the above class in order for the connection/sql injection to work on any given db parameter ? :)

Comment: you have to follow what i have written for multiple dbs But In Yii we can't create relation between two dbs. For this purpose we have to execute custom sql queries. Still i did not get your problem ?

Comment: my system, linkbook.co will parse daily some websites and store the new urls/articles in the main database; but, i have a limit of 2 GB / website, so i have secondary db's; each website s assigned to a db; the id starts from 1 and goes to N; N=1,infinite; the databases are named like : linkbook1, linkbook2, linkbook3, ..., linkbookN; i cant figure it out how to insert the urls/articles in the db where the website has been assigned to

Comment: so, each info, should go also in a secondary db; this is where i got stuck, as i dont know how to change the db dinamicaly, using a ID

Comment: very nice. You are creating database dynamically so you need to build your own component that dynamically create a connection to a database and their you will pass the database name as argument or you can create your own extension to do this. I think yii does not have any such thing to manage it.

Comment: please also modify your question that you add database dynamically & want to make connection to them

Comment: i think that the question has been asked, i will open a new question regarding the dinamyc thinghy