# Yii mongodbsuite two and more database connections

Tags: mongodb, yii

How to make two or more database connections in Yii mongodbsuite?

I added 2 DB components in main.php:

```
'components' => array(

    'mongodb' => array(
        'class'             => 'common\extensions\MongoDB',
        'connectionString'  => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/table1',
        'dbName'            => 'table1',
        'fsyncFlag'         => false,
        'persistentConnection' => 'x',
        'replicaSet'        => false,
        'safeFlag'          => true,
        'useCursor'         => false,
    ),

    'mongodb2' => array(
        'class'             => 'common\extensions\MongoDB',
        'connectionString'  => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/table2',
        'dbName'            => 'table2',
        'fsyncFlag'         => false,
        'persistentConnection' => 'x',
        'replicaSet'        => false,
        'safeFlag'          => true,
        'useCursor'         => false,
    ),

)
```

But how to use `mongodb2` in query (ex: ->findByAttributes()) i don't know.
Please provide some example queries using the `mongodb2` connection above.

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778422/yii-multiple-databases-connection-fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just add 'mongodb2' => array   to  'components' => array and add to models (ex: User) who extends EMongoDocument:

```
public function getMongoDBComponent() {return Yii::app()->mongodb2;}
```

And it is work!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Multiple db support in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/).

Basically you have to modify your active record class by overriding the `getDbConnection()` methods. (In the given link you have a better example using an intermediate inheritance layer)

Comment: In my project all models extends \web\extensions\MongoDocument (NOT CActiveRecord). So Multiple db support in Yii not work for me.