# Yii choose database depends on parametr

Tags: php, yii

I have an application and databases (all have the same structure). I need to set Yii to connect to the specyfic database. Example:

http://mylink.com/index.php/ProjectName/Controller/Action

But i also have a part of application which is independent and its connecting to one "global" database, the urls should be like this:

http://mylink.com/index.php/Controller/Action

I dont know how to do this. And what is more if im in a single Project all links which Yii creates should also contain project name

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `Modules` and `Multiples databases`.

For to use `modules` you have to create under the folder `/modules` the similar structure of Yii, as example:

```
ProjectName/
   ProjectName.php            
   components/                
      views/                  
   controllers/               
      DefaultController.php   
   extensions/                
   models/                    
   views/                     
      layouts/                
      default/                
         index.php
```

**Reference of: [How to create modules.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module)**

I like the solution where you override the class `CActiveRecord` and create a class for each database connection, for example:

```
class CActiveRecord_Db1 extends CActiveRecord{
    public function getDbConnection(){
    ....
    }
}
```

And on your models, you extend the specific `CActiveRecord`.

**[This answer has a detailed way to connect to different DBs dynamically.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778422/yii-multiple-databases-connection-fails)**

Comment: its not a problem to choose config file depends on $_GET[project], problem is with URL's

Comment: Yes, you want to use modules.... Create a folder structure under the folder modules, it's exatly what do you want

Comment: I dont want to use modules for every database. I load just one depending on Project

Comment: No, but you have to use as module for each "project", and each project will connect with different DB. Isn't what do you want to?

Comment: i want to change config in bootstrap depending on URL

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what do you need. Which configuration in Bootstrap do you want to change based on Projects (Controllers)? As I said, you can direct your models for different DB's overriding the class `CActiveRecord`. (Or yet dynamically, as the link in my answer).

You achieve the folder structure that you showed with Yii `modules`. 

Please, edit your question to make than clearer, if you leave like this, will be unlikely someone answer you.

Answer (score 0):

Using modules is the perfect way for you. Declare several db connections in config/main.php (for example 'db' and 'db_custom'). 
Then there are two ways:

1. You can reset db component in module:

   ```
   class MyModule extends CWebModule
   {
       public function init()
       {
            Yii::app()->setComponent('db',Yii::app()->getComponent('db_custom'));
       }
    }
   ```
2. Another way is to separate config into basic and custom config for module (config/main.php and config/mymodule.php). In config/mymodule.php write:

   ```
   $aMainConfig = require(dirname(__FILE__).'/main.php');
   $aMainConfig['components']['db'] = $aMainConfig['components']['db_custom'];
   return $aConf;
   ```

So you change main db component and you module will use another database.